# PHP array file insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

How do I insert this into the database?

I have this file:

```
[player_id] => 70658
[mobile_number] => 09********
[name] => gorbani
[password] => ******
[verification_code] => KUTY6U
[subscription] => 0
[gold] => 147350
[date_joined] => 2011-04-26 20:02:40
[free_spin] => 0
[player_status] => 1
[scriptedSpin] => PLG
[message_flag] => N
[gold_award] => 0
```

Thats just 1 entry out of 300,000 or more in one text file.
I need to automatically, insert the ff. into a mysql db where only the

```
mobile_number
name
password
gold
```

will be taken and inserted.

Thank you.

Regards,
Mehihi

That is how the file is being formatted:

```
[player_id] => 70658
[mobile_number] => 09********
[name] => gorbani
[password] => ******
[verification_code] => KUTY6U
[subscription] => 0
[gold] => 147350
[date_joined] => 2011-04-26 20:02:40
[free_spin] => 0
[player_status] => 1
[scriptedSpin] => PLG
[message_flag] => N
[gold_award] => 0

[player_id] => 70659
[mobile_number] => 09********
[name] => gorbani2
[password] => ******
[verification_code] => 22222
[subscription] => 0
[gold] => 147350
[date_joined] => 2011-04-26 20:02:40
[free_spin] => 0
[player_status] => 1
[scriptedSpin] => PLG
[message_flag] => N
[gold_award] => 0
```

and so on..

I have tried this but no good:

```
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $myarray as $row ) {
$sql[] = '('.$row['ID'].', "'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['NAME']).'","'.$row['PRICE'].'")';}
mysql_real_query('INSERT INTO table (ID, NAME,PRICE) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What is your question? [Please read the FAQ about what questions oen should post!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: That's exactly how the file contents looks like? Any kind of separator between the records or just "each chunk of 13 lines is one record, happy parsing"?

Answer (score 1):

When you will have your associative array do the following:

First prepare a SQL query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." ("; 
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{ 
  $sql .= key($arr); 
  if ($i < (count($arr)-1))
  { 
    $sql .= ", "; 
  } else $sql .= ") "; 
  next($arr); 
} 
reset($arr); 
$sql .= "VALUES ("; 
for ($j=0; $j<count($arr); $j++)
{ 
  $sql .= "'".current($arr)."'"; 
  if ($j < (count($arr)-1))
  { 
    $sql .= ", "; 
  } else $sql .= ") "; 
  next($arr); 
}
```

Now, since you have your SQL query stored in $sql you just execute a query in your preffered method.

Note: mysql_query is depricated, you should use PDO or something else instead.